# Marking the minimum point in a matplotlib plot

Tags: matplotlib, plot

Example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
xlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ylist = [1, 5, 3, 4, 2]
zlist = [6, -3, 6, -1, 2]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(xlist, ylist, zlist)
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)   
plt.show()
```

A simple 3d scatter plot... let's say I want the minimum point (on the z axis) to be a different color. So that point be the second point: x = 2, y = 5, z = -3. What is the simplest way to achieve this? (note: if there is a tie for minimum, all minima should be highlighted)

My workaround is to use `min` to find the min in `zlist`, then say `min_index = zlist.index(min(zlist))`, then remove the entry (and save it) at `min_index` from `xlist`, `ylist`, and `zlist`. Then to plot that point individually with another `ax.scatter` command of just one point (the minimum). But that seems pretty inelegant, and it doesn't work for ties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use NumPy to find the minimum value in `zlist` and generate a boolean array which is True where `zlist` equals `zmin` (note this could happen more than once). Then use `np.where` to generate an array which is `red` when `mask` is `True` and `blue` otherwise:

```
zmin = np.min(zlist)
mask = np.array(zlist) == zmin
color = np.where(mask, 'red', 'blue')
```

You cand then pass `color=color` to `ax.scatter` to create the desired scatter plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

xlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ylist = [1, 5, 3, 4, 2]
zlist = [6, -3, 6, -1, 2]
zmin = np.min(zlist)
mask = np.array(zlist) == zmin
color = np.where(mask, 'red', 'blue')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(xlist, ylist, zlist, color=color)
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)   
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds. Very clever use of `where`. This is definitely the right solution with minimum waste. +1

Comment: Today I learned about "where"... numpy really has a function for anything, thanks